# Can you put poison on a weapon that is already enchanted?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I just started playing Skyrim and I am level 12, but I have a question before I get too invested into crafting perks. Can a weapon that is enchanted have poison applied to it as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use both.

Poisoned and Enchanted-ness are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Is worth noting that the Elemental Fury shout can't be used if your weapon is enchanted. Unless they patched it.

Comment: @Tristan that annoyed me - most people I think will end up with an enchanted weapon at some point (no real reason not to), which renders that shout considerably less useful. don't see what's so wrong about being able to swing an enchanted axe a little faster!